# Improve sync of several databases based on rules

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, synchronization

I'm trying to decrease the time taken to perform a bi-directional synchronisation of two databases. First database is cloud based, and the second a LocalDB.

[image: DB Dataflow]

Data should only be downloaded/uploaded based on certain rules, currently I am using Linq CreateQuery to create the SQL queries (eg: User 1 on database 1 can only down/upload Ford car data, user 2 on database 1 can only down/upload Nissan data).

As more and more records get added to the databases the sync time increases, this is because the current design doesn't have any way of knowing what records are new / it has already downloaded or uploaded.

I've been reading about merge replication which initially looked like a good solution, however it doesn't support the level of dynamic/parameterized filters I require.

Comment: merge replication does support filters that you can customize as you would like it. we use it in production to send regional data specific to their regions while keeping the entire company's data at one central point.

Comment: @kowieleroux Thanks, I can see that the filters allow full SQL syntax which I didn't notice before. Also are you using MS LocalDB at the regional locations?

Comment: yes. we use sql server express at the regional locations. our setup doesn't merge to a cloud db first like yours though